# Different designs for different devices ios

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have been creating an application for iPhone and iPad. I am using Auto Layout (wAny and hAny). Now I want a separate design for iPhone 4s alone. How can I use separate designs for this device. I already completed most of the designs with this wAny and hAny. How can I change this.

Edit:

I want to change only few view controller not all the designs.

Comment: make a separate storyboard and load it runtime based on current device resolution.

Comment: So Do I need to move all the Viewcontroller to that storyboard?

Comment: you said Now I want a separate design for iPhone 4 alone. so there will be different designs for that

Comment: just use adaptive layout feature of size classes under compact width and compact height

Comment: You want to specify separate design for `3.5 inch` or you need to adjust height?

Comment: @iAnurag If I use compact width and compact height how can I handle constraints. I am using constraints for some animations width, height changes.

Comment: @Rafeek Not only height I want many design changes in same screen.

Comment: Compact height, compact wont help you in `3.5 inch` screen better to be adjust it in a codes. The reason is if you check in the size classes itself, It will helps to design for all iPhone sizes. or design seprate nib for it and load dynamically

Comment: When u use adaptive layout xcode automatically handles installation of constraints as per size class u r using.

Comment: If its for all iPhone sizes you can design it in compact width, any height.

Comment: Yes. Agreed with Rafeek.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to go with different storyboards. You can add 2 views inside that viewcontroller's(for which the design is different) view and toggle it programmatically depending on the device. Regarding autolayout, set wAny and hAny and add constraints accordingly.

VC.view
 -iPhone 4 View
 -Other device's view
This can be done in storyboard only.

So programmatically when loading the vc, check the device and show the specific view hiding the other view. In this case in future, even if the design is normalized, you can easily use the same view with change in one line of code.

This is necessary if the design is totally different. Or if it's just few sub views which are different, I think you should write some code to hide and unhide the subviews acc to the device.

I am a novice in iOS, please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Better to go with design it as separate controls if you have design changes and load it conditionally for `3.5 inch` screens . If its a simple changes (easily managed through codes) then go with codes itself.